# Jackson - ignore Map superclass when serializing

Tags: json, serialization, dictionary, jackson, resteasy

I have a few model classes that extend `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`: they define getters and setters which wrap the Map's get and put methods. I am trying to serialize instances of these classes using Jackson (with RESTEasy), but Jackson refuses to pay attention to my getters, which are annotated with `@JsonProperty`. Instead, it is only serializing the key-value pairs of the backing map. I tried using `@JsonAutoDetect` to disable auto-detection for all methods and fields, but that didn't change anything.  Is there a way to prevent Jackson from automatically serializing a Map, or must I create new model classes that don't extend `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a few model classes that extend `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`: they define getters and setters which wrap the Map's get and put methods

This is a classic example of when *not* to use inheritance: you're finding that some other piece of code (i.e. Jackson) is treating your class like an instance of its superclass, which isn't what you want it to do. In cases like these (and also in general), it's usually better to use composition rather than inheritance.

I recommend rewriting your model class to *contain* a map, rather than extending one. You get much more control than way, and the resulting model is less brittle. If you need to view your model as a `Map`, then implement an `asMap` method (or something similar) which renders that view.

Comment: Thanks for your response, skaffman. I was actually considering moving to a composition-based approach. `LinkedHashMap` is actually not a direct superclass of my model classes; instead, they extend MongoDB's `BasicDBObject`, which allows me to easily persist them. However, I may be trying to use these objects for too many purposes. Adding toDBObject() and fromDBObject() methods should work.  However, I'm still curious as to whether or not there's a way to prevent Jackson from doing its default `Map` serialization. Is there a way to disable a serializer for a specific type?

Answer (score 11):

I agree with @skaffman's response. But if you could not easily change inheritance structure drastically, there may be ways around this.

One possibility is that if you do have an interface that defines getters/setters, you could add

```
@JsonSerialize(as=MyInterface.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as=MyInterface.class)
```

which would force Jackson to only use whatever is available via specific interface.

Custom serializers/deserializers are also a possibility, but that's quite a bit of work.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own `org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializerProvider` which extends Jackson's `org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider` and overwrite method `_createDeserializer`:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
...

class MyDeserializerProvider extends StdDeserializerProvider {

    @Override
    protected JsonDeserializer<Object> _createDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, JavaType type, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        if (type.isMapLikeType()) {       // (1)
            return this._factory.createBeanDeserializer(config, this, type, property);
        } else {
            return super._createDeserializer(config, type, property);
        }
    }
}
```

(1) use if-condition that meets your needs

The custom deserializer is registered directly at the ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.setDeserializerProvider(new MyDeserializerProvider());
```

I tested this with Jackson 1.9.11.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of jackson (>= 2.9, I guess) simply annotate your class with

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
```