# How to serialize with Jackson a java.util.Map based class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class which looks like this:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public class MyMap implements Map<String, String>
{
    protected Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    protected String myProperty = "my property";
    public String getMyProperty()
    {
        return myProperty;
    }
    public void setMyProperty(String myProperty)
    {
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }

    //
    // java.util.Map mathods implementations
    // ...
}
```

And a main method with this code:

```
            MyMap map = new MyMap();
            map.put("str1", "str2");

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
            mapper.getSerializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
```

When executing this code I'm getting the following output: {"str1":"str2"}

My question is why the internal property "myProperty" is not serialized with the map?
What should be done to serialize internal properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you will end up with implementing your own serializer which will handle your custom Map type. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718659/jackson-ignore-map-superclass-when-serializing) for more information.

If you choose to replace inheritance with composition, that is to make your class to include a map field not to extend a map, then it is pretty easy to solve this using [the @JsonAnyGetter annotation](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html).

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonMap {

    public static class Bean {
        private final String field;
        private final Map<String, Object> map;

        public Bean(String field, Map<String, Object> map) {
            this.field = field;
            this.map = map;
        }

        public String getField() {
            return field;
        }

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
            return map;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Bean map = new Bean("value1", Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("key1", "value2"));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"field":"value1","key1":"value2"}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I chose to try the composition pattern and it did the job. Just one note, I didn't need to use the @JsonAnyGetter annotation for my map getter.

Comment: @odavid Good! Note that if you are not using JsonAnyGetter then your json looks like: {"field":"value1","map":{"key1":"value2"}}