# Using Jackson to Serialize/Deserialize a Polymorphic Map with Properties

Tags: serialization, hashmap, jackson, deserialization

I am currently using Guava's ForwardingMap as a base class and have numerous types that extend it.  I need to maintain the Map type because instances need to be treated as such in consumers.  So, even though internally the ForwardingMap using composition the external interface still has to be a map.

As a map, deserializing just key-value properties using @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter work fine but, I also need to take into account custom properties, using @JsonProperty, which may also be a part of the instance as well.

So, when serializing or deserializing I want all of the entries and any custom properties which may be a part of the extended class.

I have looked at numerous types of solutions, such as using the Shape.OBJECT and apply interfaces, but none of them seem to work properly for me.  I believe I need to create a custom deserializer/serializer to handle the bean + map processing in Jackson but cannot find any examples as to how to do this.

These links help to explain what I am trying to do with no luck:

- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2013/10/entry_482.html
- [How to serialize with Jackson a java.util.Map based class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633838/how-to-serialize-with-jackson-a-java-util-map-based-class) (cannot change base of ForwardingMap)
- [Jackson - ignore Map superclass when serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718659/jackson-ignore-map-superclass-when-serializing) (cannot change base because it needs to remain a Map)

Ideally, I would like an example or pointer of how to serialize and deserialize an instance that extends ForwardingMap using @JsonAnySetter and @JsonAnyGetter and has custom properties using @JsonProperty as well.

I would want my output to look like

```
    "modules": {
        "MyModel": { <-- extends ForwardingMap<>
            "domain": "typeinfo",
            "property":"hello",    <-- comes from @JsonProperty
            "another": "GoodBye",  <-- comes from @JsonAnyGetter
            "another2": 50  <-- comes from @JsonAnyGetter
        }
    }
```