# Jackson (de)serialization of subclass

Tags: java, jackson

I can deserialize an object of this class:

```
public class MyCoolClass {
    public UUID uuid;
    public String name;
    public BookingPeriod openPeriod;
}
```

But as soon as I extend, it all crashes:

```
public class MyCoolClass extends TreeSet<Table> {
    // ...same
}
```

`TreeSet` is related to implementation.

Exception I catch is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `test.MyCoolClass` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "uuid": "e64c15af-adb0-437e-9fb8-7ad7e793b877",
  "name": "Something-That-Can-Be-Opened",
  "openPeriod": {
    "from": "19:30",
    "to": "23:30"
  }
}"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

When used without inheritance, program runs as expected.

**"19:30"** gets deserialized into `LocalTime`

Comment: By extending `TreeSet`, your class is actually a `Set`. Jackson handles `Set` by expecting a JSON array.

Comment: So you want it to create an empty set? I assume `Table` is `Comparable`.

Comment: @shmosel Yeh, it is. I want an empty set to be created initially, or an implementation could pass some tables to a setter

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this might be the case... Is there any way to alter this behaviour?

Comment: It's complicated. Why does `MyCoolClass` need to be a `Set`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8718659/1553851

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was lazy to delegate to a field so I decided to just extend. That probably was a poor decision